# Add scoped variable per row iteration in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, rdd

I'm reading multiple html files into a dataframe in Spark.
I'm converting elements of the html to columns in the dataframe using a custom udf

```scala
val dataset = spark
  .sparkContext
  .wholeTextFiles(inputPath)
  .toDF("filepath", "filecontent")
  .withColumn("biz_name", parseDocValue(".biz-page-title")('filecontent))
  .withColumn("biz_website", parseDocValue(".biz-website a")('filecontent))

  ...

  def parseDocValue(cssSelectorQuery: String) = 
     udf((html: String) => Jsoup.parse(html).select(cssSelectorQuery).text())
```

Which works perfectly, however each `withColumn` call will result in the parsing of the html string, which is redundant.

Is there a way (without using lookup tables or such) that I can generate 1 parsed Document (`Jsoup.parse(html)`) based on the "filecontent" column per row and make that available for all `withColumn` calls in the dataframe?

Or shouldn't I even try using DataFrames and just use RDD's ?

Comment: can you update with sample text strings?

Comment: I am having issues with the non-parallelization of 'wholeTextFiles` in essence (e.g. 2 executors on 64 core cluster, before I can even repartition), so I'll probably rewrite the entire thing. I will update & look at the suggestions when I tackled that problem. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: did you get it solved or something else?

Comment: No I discovered that I have a bigger problem, which I have to tackle first. Don't know if the solution will bring me back to this point, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final answer was in fact quite simple:

Just map over the rows and create the object ones there

```scala
def docValue(cssSelectorQuery: String, attr: Option[String] = None)(implicit document: Document): Option[String] = {
    val domObject = document.select(cssSelectorQuery)

    val domValue = attr match {
      case Some(a) => domObject.attr(a)
      case None => domObject.text()
    }

    domValue match {
      case x if x == null || x.isEmpty => None
      case y => Some(y)
    }
  }

 val dataset = spark
      .sparkContext
      .wholeTextFiles(inputPath, minPartitions = 265) 
      .map {
        case (filepath, filecontent) => {
          implicit val document = Jsoup.parse(filecontent)

          val customDataJson = docJson(filecontent, customJsonRegex)


          DataEntry(
            biz_name = docValue(".biz-page-title"),
            biz_website = docValue(".biz-website a"),
            url = docValue("meta[property=og:url]", attr = Some("content")),
            ...
            filename = Some(fileName(filepath)),
            fileTimestamp = Some(fileTimestamp(filepath))
          )
        }
      }
      .toDS()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably rewrite it as follows, to do the parsing and selecting in one go and put them in a temporary column:

```
val dataset = spark
  .sparkContext
  .wholeTextFiles(inputPath)
  .withColumn("temp", parseDocValue(Array(".biz-page-title", ".biz-website a"))('filecontent))
  .withColumn("biz_name", col("temp")(0))
  .withColumn("biz_website", col("temp")(1))
  .drop("temp")

def parseDocValue(cssSelectorQueries: Array[String]) =
udf((html: String) => {
  val j = Jsoup.parse(html)
  cssSelectorQueries.map(query => j.select(query).text())})
```